# Camera.main is null when performing raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Code that generates an error:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position), Vector2.zero);
        if (hit && hit.collider != null && hit.collider.name == "leftTapArea")
        {
            hit.transform.name = "Hit";
        }
    }
}
```

It says that something is wrong with this string:

> RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position), Vector2.zero);

Error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   leftScript.Update () (at Assets/leftScript.cs:16)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only thing that can return null in your code is `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint`. It means that `Camera.main` is `null`. For `Camera.main` to be initialized, the camera must have the `MainCamera` tag.

Select the Camera GameObject then change the tag to MainCamera.

[image]

If you don't want your camera to be in the MainCamera tag, you can also find wit directly with `GameObject.Find` then get the `Camera` component from it.

```
Camera cam;

void Start()
{
    cam = GameObject.Find("NameOfCameraGameObject").GetComponent<Camera>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position), Vector2.zero);
        if (hit && hit.collider != null && hit.collider.name == "leftTapArea")
        {
            hit.transform.name = "Hit";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.

Comment: I see what you meant by my duplicated question.... Let me try your solution... Thanks.

Comment: GREAT!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have in your scene an active gameobject with the `Camera` component and the tag "MainCamera"

[image: Tag]
<sub>(source: [unity3d.com](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/TagDropdown.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not add a "Main Camera" gameobject per default to the scene and initialize it during runtime, this is how you would do it properly:

```
//This is needed in order for UnityEngine.Camera.main... to work
public const string CameraGameObjectName = "MainCamera";
```

content of the init method:

```
GameObject cameraGameObject = new GameObject(CameraGameObjectName);
cameraGameObject.tag = CameraGameObjectName;
UnityEngine.Camera camera = cameraGameObject.AddComponent<UnityEngine.Camera>();
Transform cameraPosition = cameraGameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
```

You can access it afterwards from anywhere with:

```
UnityEngine.Camera.main.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. But my error is the name of the camera script, i named it Camera with capital "C". So i could not access to Camera.main. And i changed the name of the script more importantly the name of the class from 'Camera' to 'camera'. Then there are no more errors. This is late but i suppose this might help others.