# Raycast does not hit an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Why this code does not print anything after a touch?

```
    void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position), Vector2.zero);
        if (hit)
        {
            print(hit.transform.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it wants you to give us more information. E.g. do the objects you try to hit with the raycast have a collider2d of some sort, might they be set to ignore raycasts?

Comment: What type of Object are you trying to hit? Putting screenshot of it while it is selected would be helpful. Also, put  `print("inside touch");` in  `if (Input.touchCount > 0)`. You have to tell us what is failing in the code.

Comment: Also shouldn't you be looking for the name of the gameobject the transform is attached to? So something like `hit.transform.gameObject.name`?

Comment: @Programmer why this Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.touches[0].position) returns the Camera position instead of touch position?

Comment: Your last question/comment is false. Please consider answering my question my first comment. Don't ignore other comments too since their comments means that they want to help you.

Comment: @Programmer ok, sorry. It's an empy 2d gameObject with a box collider. Screenshot: http://screenshot.ru/4efa2bc6302e857af87d5c5555dad8f5.png

Comment: @GunnarB. I found that Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position) returns a camera position. Does it should work like that?

Comment: @UnholySheep idk it returned the name with this `hit.transform.name` when I used Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition instead of Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position)

Comment: Hi, the code in your question should be working. What are you trying to do ?What is the exact problem you are having? Please answer these two questions

Comment: @Programmer Oh, I had to used this `Vector3 V2toV3 = new Vector3(Input.GetTouch(0).position.x, Input.GetTouch(0).position.y, 10f);` because ScreenToWorldPoint receives a Vector3 argument where x and y are the screen coordinates, and z is the distance from the camera. Since Input.GetTouch(0).position.z is always 0, what I was getting is the camera position. Now it's working

Comment: I've been using that code and it should work. The code in your [last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659982/raycast-returns-null) question is even working. I can't tell why this is not working for you. Maybe you are using old Unity version? Glad you fixed your own problem.

Comment: I suspect that there should be another collider (raycast starts in or near it) and since raycast only hits one target then ray never get past that

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit;

        if (Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position), Vector2.zero, out hit))
        {
            print(hit.transform.name);
        }
    }
```