# Unity C# : MainCamera - Tag rotates Canvas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I have a Canvas with RenderMode set to "World Space".

I want the Canvas to Look At the main Camera, so i wrote this code:

```
SimpleCanvas.transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform);
```

it works perfect, but i get the error "Null Reference Exception" just like this guy [Unity C# : Camera.main returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553057/unity-c-sharp-camera-main-returns-null)

So i read that you should set your Camera's Tag to "MainCamera". 
When i do this, the camera no longer returns null, but my Canvas gets rotated by 180 degrees and looks mirrored to the camera.

What can i do to stop the rotation / or get rid of the null Reference Exception?

Answer (score 0):

okay i found the answer by myself ... very easy, i just added:

```
SimpleCanvas.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
```